# nvidia-settings does not load xorg.conf saved settings at startup

Tags: debian, nvidia, multi-monitor, monitors

I tried making a `/home/name/.local/share/nvidiaconf.sh` file with

```
nvidia-settings -load-config-only
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-0: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0, DP-2: 1920x1080_75 +0+0, HDMI-0: 1280x768_60 +3840+0"
```

and adding `chmod +x /home/name/.local/share/nvidiaconf.sh` to `/home/name/.bashrc`.

On restart the settings are not loaded (`DP-0` and `DP-2` reset to `+0+0` position).

I managed to get it working on my previous install of the same version of Debian, but I forgot what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `chmod +x` line in your bashrc. You only need to make a file executable once and the file will persist that permission.

Instead, you need to call the `/home/name/.local/share/nvidiaconf.sh` script from your bashrc so that it the commands are executed. So, just remove the leading chmod +x from what you have. To run it by name add a shebang line as the first line of the script, e.g. `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Note that .bashrc is loaded every time a bash shell is opened, e.g. every time you open a new terminal with bash. These commands sound like they only need to be ran once, and thus you may want to instead move the line calling the nvidiaconf.sh file to .profile or .bash_profile which won't be loaded for every new nonlogin shell.

This article explains the relationship betwwen login/nonlogin/interactive shells ahd .bashrc vs .bash_profile.

https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/

Comment: I added `sudo sh nvidiaconf.sh` at the end of `.profile` but it still doesn't load it. I tried the same command in `.bashrc` and it does load the monitors correctly when I open a terminal. So there is some progress.

Comment: Does it require sudo to run? This may be better suited not in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` but instead a systemd service file so you don't need to enter in sudo. As far is not working from .profile, how did you test that? What is your desktop manager, if any?

Comment: Have you checked out section `3. Load settings automatically`? https://man.archlinux.org/man/nvidia-settings.1

Answer (score 0):

I finally remembered what I did.

In the `Session and Startup` app in the `Application Autostart` tab I `+Add` a new application called `nvidiaconfload` with the command `sudo nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-0: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0, DP-2: 1920x1080_75 +0+0, HDMI-0: 1280x768_60 +3840+0"` with Trigger: `on login`.

[image]